# Переадресация портов на сервере Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, веб-сервер, ethernet

При подключение к сайту открывается 80 порт с Nginx, а весь функционал крутится на 3000 порте. Можно ли сделать так что бы при открытие сайта пользователя перенаправляло на 3000 порт? OC: Ubuntu 18

Comment: *"а весь функционал крутится на 3000 порте"* --- это как?)

Comment: у nginx есть насттройка `server {
    listen 3000;
}`  ....... собссн

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да у автора как обычно на 3000 какой-нибудь nodejs/python сервер поднят.

Comment: Можно, но обычно используют какой-нибудь обратный прокси (nginx/apache/traefik/что-то ещё). И информации об этом куча

Comment: рекомендую proxy_pass nginx

Comment: Вот тут рабочие примеры: https://docs.gitea.com/administration/reverse-proxies